# iFrame within Fancybox not display html in full page

Tags: iframe, fancybox

I have a problem that html page not displayed in full page consistently. Need to click toggle size button to expand the html page. Any problem with the code as attached below ?

Any method to ensure each html is displayed in full page ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
    'padding'       : '1',
    'margin'        : '2',
    'autoScale'     : false,
    'width'         : '100%',
    'height'        : '100%',
        'type'          : 'iframe',
    'autoPlay'      : false,
    'playSpeed'     : 10500,
    closeBtn        : false,
    iframe : {
       scrolling : 'no'
    },
    helpers     : {
       title    : { type : 'inside' },
       buttons  : {}
    }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Profitable Plan

Comment: `'height':'100%'` means that fancybox will display 100% of the viewport ... try setting `fitToView:false`

Answer (score 1):

Just set `autoSize: false`. See example - http://jsfiddle.net/j8MQW/

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    autoSize        :  false,
    'padding'       : '1',
    'margin'        : '2',
    'autoScale'     : false,
    'width'         : '100%',
    'height'        : '100%',
    'type'          : 'iframe',
    'autoPlay'      : false,
    'playSpeed'     : 10500,
    closeBtn        : false,
    iframe : {
       scrolling : 'no'
    },
    helpers     : {
       title    : { type : 'inside' },
       buttons  : {}
    }
 });
```